# How to write a shopping queue line plugin with a queue button?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, json

I am familiar a little with HTML and Css and an epsilon with PhP, Js, SQL and JavaScript. I want to write a shopping queue line plugin with a queue button (If there is no similar free WP plugin) such that users after registration can join to queue by pressing  (one time or cancel) queue button and wait in the queue until all other left the queue. Briefly:

1. (Register and) log in
2. press queue button
3. User can cancel out his/her queue or wait until his/her turn
4. After the seller presses the next button, a success message will appear in the buyer's account.

I have found [this js queue](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-queue/2.0.2/queue.js) but I don't know how to use and add it to WordPress. I don't expect for a full answer. I just want a starting point and some hints.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/crowdhandler-virtual-waiting-room/

That plugin requires an account with that service, however they have a free tier.

Comment: I don't know what that plugin is. There is no information or demo on website to know what it do.

Comment: It is a waiting room/queue functionality. Service is here: https://www.crowdhandler.com/ and info on installation https://www.crowdhandler.com/support/solutions/articles/80000903583-wordpress-integration-getting-started unfortunately doesn't give examples on integration.